# How to connect Jenkins with SonarQube 4.3?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I try to migrate my build jobs from Hudson to Jenkins (version 2.32.1). The Maven build works fine, but the Maven build step for SonarQube doesn't work. I use Jenkins SonarQube Plugin version 2.5.

My SonarQube configuration (following [Adding SonarQube Scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AddingSonarQubeServer)):

[image: SonarQube configuration]

My build environment (following [Configuring a SonarQube Scanner using environment variables](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-ConfiguringaSonarQubeScannerusingenvironmentvariables)):

[image: Build enviroment]

My Maven build step (following [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven)):

[image: Build step]

Jenkins console log:

```
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.3
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "cp1252"
INFO: Work directory: /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/test/workspace/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3
[INFO] [15:34:56.104] Load batch settings
[INFO] [15:34:56.248] User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [15:34:56.254] Install plugins
[INFO] [15:34:56.320] Install JDBC driver
[WARN] [15:34:56.329] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
[INFO] [15:34:56.329] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
[ERROR] Fail to connect to database
```

Logs show, that Jenkins used the wrong database URL (H2 instead of PostgreSQL).

What did I wrong?

Comment: I strongly update to update your version to 5.6.3 (LTS)

Comment: @Teryk - SonarSource Team: I have already an instance of SonarQube 5.6.3 for our Java 8 build jobs. But I need our old instance of SonarQube 4.3 for our Java 6 and Java 7 build jobs.

Comment: You can analyze Java 6 and 7 projects on SQ 5.6+. Compile with whatever you like, but _run the analysis_ with Java 8

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team: Unfortunately Jenkins has no feature to run build steps with different JDK/JREs. I can only choose one Java version for the whole build job.

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team: In Hudson I could run SonarQube scan as a post build action and use a different JDK/JRE, but that is not possible with Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

I found a work-around. I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-jenkins/blob/e43ed498d2a25272f9991eeeb29aa922397a2f93/src/main/webapp/help-buildWrapper.html) of Jenkins SonarQube Plugin (because I couldn't find the documentation) and found a list of exposed environment variables:

> Inject environment variables related to the chosen SonarQube installation. 
>         
>         The following variables may be set depending on the configuration:
>
> - SONAR_HOST_URL
> - SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN
> - SONAR_LOGIN
> - SONAR_PASSWORD
> - SONAR_JDBC_URL
> - SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME
> - SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD
> - SONAR_EXTRA_PROPS
> - SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL - supplies the correct Maven goal based on the "Version of sonar-maven-plugin" specified for the SonarQube instance.
>
> These variables are useful when configuring a SonarQube analysis using standard build steps such as Maven, Gradle, Ant, and command line scripts. 
>       **This feature is not needed if you're using "SonarQube Scanner" or "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild" build steps.**

After adding `-Dsonar.jdbc.url=$SONAR_JDBC_URL` to my build step:

[image]
it works fine.